# Как в XML файле нарисовать линию посередине?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть такой XML

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/ntz_color_yellow" />
<corners android:radius="2dp" />

</shape>
```

Если я задаю его своему вью как бекграунд то получаю контур вокруг своего вью. Мне нужно добавить в этот XML **вертикальную** линию посередине. Я знаю как можно нарисовать в XML линию **горизонтальную**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="#000000">
</stroke>
</shape>
```

Но как совместить это в один XML? Чтоб был контур и посередине от края до края шла вертикальная линия? Как разделитель своего рода?

Comment: для складывания нескольких элементов используйте layer list https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По совету Chaynik'a используем layer-list. В нем второй элемент - повернутая на 90 градусов горизонтальная линия.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:thickness="0dp"
            android:color="@color/yellow">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/green" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/red"
                     />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Помог ответ [отсюда.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/)

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает, и теперь стало понятно как работать с `layer-list`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Не за что. Для меня ответ на этот вопрос тоже был поучителен)))

Answer (score 1):

используйте `LinearLayout` с horizontal ориентацией, в котором разместите две области отображения чего-либо.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/linearlayout.php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961777/android-linearlayout-horizontal-with-wrapping-children

Comment: Нет этот вариант не совсем подходит так как у меня в контейнере уже находиться один вью элемент и если я начну туда добавлять еще вью то как минимум разделители не станут посередине... Я так понимаю, что нужно именно как то нарисовать линию в XML... Если есть идея как это решить?